# problem in checking whether python 3 is installed

Tags: python, bash, python-2.7, ubuntu, python-3.7

I want to check whether python 3 is installed on my Ubuntu. I'm using this script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env sh

#install firefox if does not exist
if ! command -v python3 >/dev/null 2>&1
        then
                echo "not installed"
        else
                echo "installed"
fi
```

When I run this script, the output is `installed`, but when I check my python using `python --version`, I get this output:

```
Python 2.7.17
```

Which, as far as I know, means that the latest version of python on my Ubuntu is 2.7 not 3.x. What's wrong?

The output of `command -v python3; echo $?`:

```
/usr/bin/python3
0
```

The output of `ls -l /usr/bin/python3`:

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 9 Nov 14 09:13 /usr/bin/python3 -> python3.7
```

The output of `ls -l /usr/bin/python3.7`:

```
-rwxr-xr-x 2 root root 5102632 Oct 27 11:43 /usr/bin/python3.7
```

The output of `which python`:

```
/usr/bin/python
```

The output of `ls -l /usr/bin/python`:

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 7 Jan 19 08:04 /usr/bin/python -> python2
```

The output of `ls -l /usr/bin/python2`:

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 9 Jan 19 08:04 /usr/bin/python2 -> python2.7
```

Also I have another Ubuntu on a separate VM, the output of `python --version`, returns `command 'python' not found`, but when I execute the above commands for this VM as well, it returns similar responses (indicating that python is installed).

Comment: Add output of `command -v python3; echo $?` to your question.

Comment: Add output of `ls -l /usr/bin/python3` to your question.

Comment: Add output of `ls -l /usr/bin/python3.7` and `which python` to your question.

Comment: Check `python3 --version` instead of `python --version`

Comment: Add output of `ls -l /usr/bin/python`.

Comment: @thatotherguy so my other Ubuntu in which "python --version" returns "command not found means that python 2.x is not installed?

Comment: @Pablo You should not draw conclusions from that. If you want to see if Python 2.x is installed, check if `python2` exists

Comment: And as last step add output of `ls -l /usr/bin/python2`.

Comment: You have all the pieces of the puzzle together now. `python3.7` and `python2.7` are installed on your system and `python` is indirectly a symbolic link to `python2.7`.

Comment: @Cyrus How about my second VM? I ran the commands related to python2, but they didn't return the similar output. It means that python2 is not installed, yes? In case I don't have python2, but I have python3, will I have problem in executing .py files?

Comment: I suggest to start a new question at [Ask Ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com/tour).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0394/

Note: You can have an environment where you have both Python 2 and Python 3 installed, and `python` can point to either. (Most likely `python2` for backward compatibility purpose.) Python 3 applications should always use the `python3` command and not `python`.

Answer (score 1):

Try the `whereis` command. It will tell you where python3 is.

`whereis python`
Or better yet
`whereis python3`

The output should be a path, or a list of paths. You might see something like:

> python3: /usr/bin/python3.6m /usr/bin/python3.6 /usr/bin/python3.6m-config
>   /usr/bin/python3 /usr/bin/python3.6-config /usr/lib/python3.6 /usr/lib/python3
>   /usr/lib/python3.7 /usr/lib/python3.8 /etc/python3.6 /etc/python3 /usr/local

Then make sure your `PATH` variable has at least one of the directories above within it. The `PATH` environment variable is essentially a list of directories that contain executables (programs). When you type something on your command line your terminal program will search the directories listed in `PATH` for the executable you specified.

```
echo $PATH
```

> /home/USER/.pyenv/shims:/home/USER/.pyenv/bin:/home/USER/esp/xtensa-esp32-
>   elf/bin:/home/USER/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:
>   /sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin

You might have a directory in your `PATH` that is messing things up, or you might need to add a new directory.

Answer (score 1):

Because so many programs have been written using Python 2, many operating systems keep Python 2 in their repository, and this [isn't going to change](https://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0394/) any time soon.

So when you installed Python, it added Python 2 to /usr/bin/ (maybe /usr/bin/python2, maybe /usr/bin/python2.7, etc.), and pointed /usr/bin/python to the same location. When you installed Python 3 it *also* installed Python 3, to /usr/bin/python3.

When you test whether python3 is installed, you find that it is. According to [PEP 394](https://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0394/), /usr/bin/python should refer to Python 2. [Ubuntu documentation](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Python/3) explains what that means and what it doesn't:

> What this does not mean:
>
> /usr/bin/python will point to Python 3. **No, this is not going to happen** (unless PEP 394 advocates otherwise, which is doubtful for the foreseeable future). /usr/bin/python and /usr/bin/python2 will point to Python 2.7 and /usr/bin/python3 will point to the latest supported Python 3 version.
>
> Python 2 will be removed from the archive. **No, this is not going to happen.** We expect Python 2.7 to remain supported and available in Ubuntu for quite a long time, given that PEP 373 promises upstream bug fix maintenance support until 2020. It would be nice if we could demote Python 2 to universe, but that's currently problematic for technical reasons relating to multi-Python version support in Debian/Ubuntu.

Basically, while all development should be geared toward Python 3, the `python` command (/usr/bin/python) should point to Python 2 *in order to keep current programs from breaking*.

**If you'd like to access Python 3, it's recommended that you call python3. (You could also rebind /usr/bin/python to point to python3, but this is highly unrecommended. A more useful solution to most users would be to [create an alias to python3](https://askubuntu.com/questions/320996/how-to-make-python-program-command-execute-python-3).)**

---

Short version: Your script works. Python 3 is installed. If you want the terminal to open Python 3 when you type `python`, [add an alias](https://askubuntu.com/questions/320996/how-to-make-python-program-command-execute-python-3) `alias python=python3`.